# Using sfGuard and FOSUserBundle in paraller

Tags: symfony, symfony1, fosuserbundle, sfguard

Our client uses multiple applications that are developed with Symfony. Older use Symfony 1.3.x and newer Symfony 2.x. User management and security is based on sfGuard using Propel. The client has created own bundle for handling security with sfGuard based ORM-objects in Symfony 2. Now client wants to upgrade user management component. Current user management is made with automatic CRUD-app-generation for Symfony 1.x.

Upgrading user management to Symfony 2 Using  FOSUserBundle seems to be reasonable solution, but is it possible to use existing Symfony 1.x apps with sfGuard-plugin handling user management with FOSUserBundle?

I'm quite new to Symfony, so I would appreciate clear guidelines to resolve the issue one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

FOSUSerBundle use another kind of password storage. 
I'm sure than with FOSUserBundle is not be able to check passwords created with sfGuard.

Maybe you can use https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSAdvancedEncoderBundle for change the password encoder for FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. I'm particularly interested how easy it is to get existing tables (user & user_profile) to work with FOSUserBundle. Our client has generated ORM-classes with Propel for Symfony2, but If I understood correctly, they can't be used directly with new bundle, because it's not possible to extend Bundle's own User class with them.